# How to integrate Elastic search with cassandra?

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, jhipster, elassandra

I wanna to implement elastic search with in my app in which i'm using cassandra as db. this app is gen using Jhipster tech. anybody please suggest a way to implement elastic search using cassandra. Jhipster officials says at that time cassandra is not support elastic search.
elassandra is a way to do that but there is not proper way to how to work with elassandra.

Answer (score 1):

Elassandra exposes the standard Cassandra and Elasticsearch APIs so you should be able to use Elassandra as a drop-in for Cassandra for use with Jhipster. From a quick look, it doesn't look like Jhipster has any Elasticsearch support but I imagine you could use the REST APIs with custom code.

Cheers
Ben

Comment: JHipster [does support Elasticsearch](http://www.jhipster.tech/using-elasticsearch/) but this option isn't available with Cassandra. There isn't any technical issue, it's just that the team didn't have the time to code it, and as Cassandra is less than 2% of our generated projects, this isn't a top priority.

Comment: thnaks for response julien dubois & Ben slater.

Comment: what should i've to do. any another way...?

Comment: Given Julien's info that JHispter does support Elasticsearch, I would imagine if you use Elassandra then you could use JHispter C* support to read and write data via C* APIs and JHipster's Elasticsearch support to read and write data via the Elasticsearch API. Whichever API you chose the data will be stored in the same base tables. Elassandra has fully compatible support for both APIs so JHipster shouldn't know the difference.